# DSL script approval required even when job is authorized

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I have created a "Freestyle project" job (e.g. MainSeed) manually. The job consumes DSL script from SCM and should create a new "Freestyle project" job (e.g. SubSeed). When I start MainSeed, it fails with 
`Processing DSL script SubSeed.groovy` 
`ERROR: script not yet approved for use`

I am aware of Script Security introduced with Job DSL plugin version 1.60, therefore I use Authorize Project plugin. I configured build authorization with "Run as Specific User" and my user ID, I am admin. The job still fails with the same error.

My old seed jobs, which I created in the past, work without errors. I can seed other jobs with them. `config.xml` of old and new jobs is almost the same (same plugin versions).

Jenkins version: 2.370 
Authorize Project version: 1.4.0
Script Security version: 1183.v774b_0b_0a_a_451